# jQuery checked value different if click() or real click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox that creates some dynamic content.

On page-load I want to pre-create the dynamic content, so I call click().
But with the click(), my attribute "checked" is not set - it is set after the click function is finished??? With a real mouse-click, attribute "checked" is set in the click event.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#myCheckbox").click(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).attr('checked')=='checked'){
            console.log('checkbox is checked');
            jQuery("#container").append("<p>Dynamic content</p>");
        } else {
            console.log('checkbox is not checked');
            jQuery("#container p").remove();
        }
    });

    console.log("before: "+jQuery('#myCheckbox').attr('checked'));
    jQuery("#myCheckbox").click();
    console.log("after: "+jQuery('#myCheckbox').attr('checked'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aschmutt/3WvAK/

I can reproduce this in current Firefox, Chrome and IE, so this seems to be an "expected behaviour". But I don't see why...

Is there already a workaround or solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep remember to use `prop` method of jquery in case of setting `checked` property of checkbox, radio button.

Try this,

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#myCheckbox").change(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).prop('checked') == true){
            console.log('checkbox is checked');
            jQuery("#container").append("<p>Dynamic content</p>");
        } else {
            console.log('checkbox is not checked');
            jQuery("#container p").remove();
        }
    });

    console.log("before: "+jQuery('#myCheckbox').attr('checked'));
    jQuery("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", true).change();
    console.log("after: "+jQuery('#myCheckbox').attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: OK it works with "change" instead of "click" and "prop" instead of "attr". But I still don't know why...

Comment: When you manually call click event it first call the event and mark checkbox as check/uncheck, so in that case if condition will never returns true as checkbox was not check at that time. i mark the checkbox as check first and call change event